# DIV position ? alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show the page like this.
[image: Have to make DIV like this]

[image: Current Status]

I'm trying to make divs as the first image but current alignment is like 2nd image.

Title and Menu area has to be fixed on the top.
Please let me know what I've done wrong...

Here's the html code,

```
        <div class="menu_wrapper">
          <div class="base menu ttl_bar">
              TITLE
          </div>
          <div class="base menu ttl_big">
               MENU
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class=" map_area">
              MAP AREA
          </div>
          <div class=" contents_area" id="draggable">
            CONTENTS AREA

          </div>
```

And here is the following CSS

```
   body{margin: 0; padding:0;}
   div {width:100vw;display: inline-block;}

   .menu_wrapper {position: fixed; top:0; height: auto;}
   .menu {background-color: red; height: 100px; }
   .map_area {background-color: blue; height: 300px;}
   .contents_area {height: 500px;}

   .ttl_bar {position: relative;}
   .ttl_big {position: relative;}
```

Please help me for figuring out the problem.

Comment: either you're trying to pull the divs to the right or u want them away from left by some px. if you want them to be at right. use `float` property. else use `margin` property. Check them.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your question...

Comment: add `right:0` to your `menu-wrapper` - if you want it to be on the right - it is unclear what you are actually after

Comment: Hey, as you are new here, please mark the correct answer that helped you the best. Many people have helped out here. Just some acknowledgement keeps this community going. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding margin-top to map-area should work for you.

```
.map_area {background-color: blue; height: 300px; margin-top:200px;}
```

Also,

Remove `display:inline-block` from div style. Looks like the layout requires them to be block level only.

#### Edit

You can try this as well:

```
body{ padding-top:200px; }
.map_area{ z-index:222; }
```

Comment: Usually I've done it thru this way, but going to let divs being showed and hided. Isn't there any other way to do it , making div stacked by it self..? Thanks. !!

Comment: As you've fixed the upper 200px area, either you over-position the map-area over menu when scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. You can try out different settings with this fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/vr_driver/r73w82rv/

```
   .map_area {background-color: blue; height: 300px; padding-top: 200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The jquery solution: Where the height of the menu is calculated dynamically and margin top to map is given according to dynamic height of menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var q = $('.menu_wrapper').height();
  $('.map_area').css('margin-top', q);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu_wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.menu {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.map_area {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.contents_area {
  height: 500px;
}

.ttl_bar {
  position: relative;
}

.ttl_big {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_wrapper">
  <div class="base menu ttl_bar">
    TITLE
  </div>
  <div class="base menu ttl_big">
    MENU
  </div>
</div>

<div class=" map_area">
  MAP AREA
</div>
<div class=" contents_area" id="draggable">
  CONTENTS AREA

</div>
```

**Note:** View it on full page

Comment: Thanks I'm on tyring to handle it from JS as well. I'm worry about the performance (it's the hybrid app) though Thanks a lot !